# Pass arguments from command line to Emacs lisp function

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to pass an argument to an Emacs lisp function on the command line. I tried

```
emacs --no-splash --eval '(setq my-test-var "hello")' -l init.el t.txt
```

where `init.el` is

```
(message my-test-var)
```

but no message is shown. I am using Emacs version 24.3 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 4):

The variables `command-line-args` and `command-line-args-left` will allow you to access the arguments passed from the command line (see [this manual page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command_002dLine-Arguments.html)).

Docstring for `command-line-args`:

> Args passed by shell to Emacs, as a list of strings.
>   Many arguments are deleted from the list as they are processed.

Docstring for `command-line-args-left`:

> List of command-line args not yet processed.

Answer (score 1):

The command passed through the `--eval` argument seems to be executed only after Emacs is initialized, so you could have this in your init.el file:

```
(defvar testvar t)
(defun test-function(arg)
  (setq testvar arg)
  (message testvar))
```

And initialize Emacs with `emacs --eval '(test-function "hello")'`

Answer (score 1):

Do you *want* to use `--eval` ?

If just want a way to perform init file processing after --eval expressions have been evaluated, then I think the question needs re-wording.

However, assuming that's the case, I think `emacs-startup-hook` is as good an answer as any.

As Jesse pointed out, --eval expressions are processed after the init file (and also `after-init-hook`) have been processed.

`emacs-startup-hook` runs after command-line args have been processed, however.